# How to pass application path to task in Azure batch

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I am using Azure batch. I have an exe which I need to execute on compute nodes.

I am using this path in the azure portal in my task window "cmd /c %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_MyAppCreateRG%\CreateRG.exe -args HelloRG eastUs"

But I am getting an error: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative i am able to execute powershell script instead of exe

powershell C:\Scripts\CreateRG.ps1 -resourceGroup "MyRG" -location "eastUs"

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, the error you got is the core point of your problem. You can create a task with the command `cmd /c "echo %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_MyAppCreateRG%"` to show the exact path if it exists or not.

Just like if you want to get the environment variable PATH in windows, you should use the command `echo %PATH%`. And the result will like below:

[image]

So, if it could not show the path you want, it means the environment variable doesn't exist and you should set it up first and check then.

I suggest if you want to execute an exe, you should check if the path of it is right and if the exe already exist for you.

Comment: Yes I was missing the application package (zip file which contains exe). I added the package and I did echo of the path as you suggested and I got this as an output "D:\batch\tasks\apppackages\myappcreaterg12018-09-02-19-19". Do I have to use this path ? As now nothing is happening. Exe is not executing. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @user1037747 For you, if the path is not you want, just find the exact path of the exe which you want to execute, then use the command `cmd /c "/path/CreateRG.exe -args HelloRG eastUs"`.

Comment: @user1037747 If the answer is helpful or for more help, please me know.

Comment: Yes i need more help. If you can tell me which path i should assign for the exe to execute it will be helpfull

Comment: @user1037747 This need more details, such as the backend pool image, and where the exe from? Does it you upload or exist in the image?

Comment: No I have created a Golden image.. Added that image in the application pool. So the exe is not there in the image. The exe i have added in Application package

Comment: @user1037747 You create the image and don't you know the exact path of the exe?

Comment: @user1037747 You can try the command `cmd /c "where CreateRG.exe"` to find the exact path.

Comment: It gives me this output "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
". And i have kept my exe inside "C:\Scripts\CreateRG.exe" as i recreated the image. But it is not executing the exe

Comment: Use the command `cmd /c "dir C:"` to check if the directory Scripts exists and command `cmd /c "dir C:\Scripts"` to check if the CreateRG.exe exists.

Comment: Yes both the scripts are working fine and both are showing me folder and exe exists. So why the exe is not executing ?

Comment: @user1037747 So I don't why you cannot find the CreateRG.exe with the command `cmd /c "where CreateRG.exe"`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have mis-quoted your command to execute. Try:

```
cmd.exe /c "%AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_MyAppCreateRG%\CreateRG.exe -args HelloRG eastUs"
```