# Azure Batch Service: Passing Arguments via Command Line into Application Package on Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: c#, linux, azure, ubuntu, azure-batch

Given the following C#/.NET console application running on my Azure Batch Pool/Task:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(args[1]);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Could not parse arguments");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I pass the args when adding a command line to my tasks in a Linux/Ubuntu VM. I have tried the following with no success:

> /bin/sh -c $AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_Program_1_0/Program -args 'arg1' 'arg2'

> /bin/sh -c $AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_Program_1_0/Program -args 'arg1', 'arg2'

> /bin/sh -c $AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_Program_1_0/Program 'arg1' 'arg2'

> /bin/sh -c $AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_Program_1_0/Program  'arg1', 'arg2'

> /bin/sh -c $AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_Program_1_0/Program -i 'arg1' 'arg2'

> /bin/sh -c $AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_Program_1_0/Program -i 'arg1', 'arg2'

I am able to run the application but the arguments are not passed in and I only get to the **"Could not parse arguments"** output...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After throwing every variation possible at this (and looking at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638028/azure-batch-service-appsettings-json-not-found)) it looks like you have to concatenate the string value of the package name with the args to the environment variable in a certain way to make sure the parameters carry through to the command.

Here is what finally did it for me

```
/bin/sh -c $AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_Program_1_0"/Program 'arg1' 'arg2'"
```

Hope this helps anyone who is looking for it!